Unable to complete the RUN npm run build of apache superset while using docker desktop
This is the comand I used to create the container of superset:
docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up
It got stuck on:
Building 2619.9s (31/135)                                                                                                        docker:desktop-linux
 => CACHED [superset-init superset-node  2/12] RUN apt-get update -qq     && apt-get install         -yqq --no-install-recommends         build-ess  0.0s
 => CACHED [superset-init superset-node  3/12] RUN --mount=type=bind,target=/frontend-mem-nag.sh,src=./docker/frontend-mem-nag.sh     /frontend-mem  0.0s 
 => CACHED [superset-init superset-node  4/12] WORKDIR /app/superset-frontend                                                                        0.0s 
 => CACHED [superset-init superset-node  5/12] RUN --mount=type=bind,target=./package.json,src=./superset-frontend/package.json     --mount=type=bi  0.0s 
 => [superset superset-node  7/12] RUN npm run build                                                                                              2584.1s 
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% sealing after asset optimization
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% sealing after asset optimization
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% sealing recording
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 93% sealing recording
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 94% sealing after seal
 => => # <s> [webpack.Progress] 94% sealing after seal

It's not completing the docker compose.

whats your docker desktop version?

Use this command:
docker compose -f docker-compose-non-dev.yml up --build -d
